# Unable to Loading jquery datepicker on google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, datepicker

I am unable to load the datepicker on google maps
Here is the code

JS

```
function CreateMapTopControl(controlDiv, controlElement, controlId, map, event, response) {

    controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';
    var controlUI = document.createElement(controlElement);
    controlUI.id = controlId;
    controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, event, function() {
        response();
        return false;
    });
    return controlUI;
}


$(document).ready(function() {

    maplct.initialize(document.getElementById('mapDiv'));

    var dateDiv = document.createElement('div');
    dateSel = new CreateMapTopControl(dateDiv, "input", "dateId", maplct.mapObject, "change", getMapRoute);
    dateDiv.index = 2;
    maplct.mapObject.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP].push(dateDiv);
    $(dateSel).attr("type", "text")
    $(dateSel).attr("style", "height:15px;width:100px;");
    var curDate = new Date();
    var d = curDate.getUTCDate();
    var dd = (d < 10) ? "0" + d : d;
    var m = curDate.getUTCMonth() + 1;
    var mm = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
    var YYYY = curDate.getUTCFullYear();
    var formattedDate = YYYY + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;
    $(dateSel).val(formattedDate);
    $(dateSel).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
    $(dateSel).datepicker( "refresh" );
});
```

Map is getting loaded at the end of the file, it looks like css is not applied.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5749 seems like the css for the visual refresh interferes with that used by the DatePicker

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/p3f-0vEoM5Q

Comment: I found the solution. I missed jquery.ui css. Soon I added it started to work.